# Vue - trying to avoid changing props, with no success

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

- parent component: Groups
- child component: Modal

in Groups, I have Modal as a component.

```
<modal
                v-if="$store.getters.getClusters"
                id="editIndFeedbackModal"
                title="Edit group feedback"
                :atok="atok"
                :feedback="$store.getters.getCurrentClusterFeedback"
                :hint="$store.getters.getCurrentClusterHint"
                :grade="$store.getters.getCurrentClusterGrade"
                :nextAss="$store.getters.getCurrentClusterNextAss"
                :recRead="$store.getters.getCurrentClusterRecRead"
                :link="$store.getters.getCurrentClusterLink"
                :clusterName="$store.getters.getCurrentClusterName"
                :clusterId="$store.getters.getCurrentClusterId"
                aria-labelledby="textEditClusterName"
        />
```

In Modal, I have a bootstrap modal.

```
props: [
            'id',
            'ariaLabelledby',
            'atok',
            'file_id_arr',
            'feedback',
            'hint',
            'grade',
            'nextAss',
            'recRead',
            'link',
            'name',
            'clusterId',
            'clusterName',
        ],
```

and used in Modal template as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea v-model="feedback" name="text_feedback" id="text_feedback" 
     class="form-control" style="resize: vertical;" rows="3" placeholder=""> 
    </textarea>
    <label for="text_feedback">Feedback</label>
</div>
```

Since Modal saves this input form, I am using v-model to change the prop and thus getting the mutating props warning.

#### What I've tried:

I tried assigning the props to local data on Modal comp.:

```
data: function () {
            return {
                currentFeedback: {
                    atok: this.$props.atok,
                    feedback: this.$props.feedback,
                },
            }
        },
```

`atok` comes back great since it exists throughout the lifecycle, yet feedback is **empty** since `feedback` comes from an async operation, where this whole issue is stemming from.

the async operation is dispatched to vuex via Groups `mounted()`:

```
getAssFiles: function () {
                if (this.atok) {
                    this.$store.dispatch('GET_ASSIGNMENT_FILES', {
                        assign_token: this.atok
                    });
                }
```

Thank you kindly.

p.s.
this firm use allot of abbreviations, so ass = assignment..

> ## EDIT
>
> I've done this:

```
data: function () {
            return {
                currentFeedback: {
                    feedback: this.migrateFeedback,
                },
            }
        },
computed:{
    migrateFeedback(){
        this.currentFeedback.feedback = this.$props.feedback
    }
```

> same result, yet when using the vue console, when I click to open the data tab, it suddenly updates view and now it's there, any idea how to solve this erroneous issue?

Comment: Why are you using props instead of data ?

Comment: changed everything use vuex data instead. still no go since data retrieval is async and the components on vue get loaded immedietly.